# UnsatisfiedLinkError in imgproc.Canny after successfully loading OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

While the OpenCV has loaded successfully in the project, and Other elements like Mat and imgproc.cvtcolor have been successfully used (atleast I think so) before encountering the Canny method. The *.so files are also present in the jniLibs directory but I don't get why this error is erupting

Following are the Logs:

```
 I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Python 3:
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Interpreter:                 NOissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -fvisibility=hidden -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    08-29 12:1
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Python (for build):            /opt/pythonenv/build/bin/python2.7
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Java:
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     ant:                         /usr/local/bin/ant (ver 1.9.4)
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Java wrappers:               YES
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Java tests:                  YES
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Matlab:                        NO
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Tests and samples:
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Tests:                       YES
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Performance tests:           NO
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     C/C++ Examples:              NO
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Install path:                  /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a/install
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   cvconfig.h is in:              /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a
    08-29 12:10:16.818 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenCVManager/Helper: -----------------------------------------------------------------
    08-29 12:10:16.819 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Init finished with status 0
    08-29 12:10:16.819 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Unbind from service
    08-29 12:10:16.824 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Calling using callback
    08-29 12:10:16.824 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/LensActivity: OpenCV loaded successfully
    08-29 12:10:16.882 6248-6408/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8610_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                                  Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
                                                                                  Local Branch: 
                                                                                  Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
                                                                                  Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                  Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
    08-29 12:10:16.884 6248-6408/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    08-29 12:10:16.904 6248-6408/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    08-29 12:10:17.049 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
    08-29 12:10:24.285 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/LensActivity: File URI = file:///storage/emulated/0/Document%20Scanner/image_10.jpg
    08-29 12:10:33.369 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/LensActivity: 1 1 -1 -1
    08-29 12:10:33.369 6248-6248/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner D/LensActivity: file:///storage/emulated/0/Document%20Scanner/image_10.jpg
    08-29 12:10:33.434 6248-6262/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.494ms
    08-29 12:10:35.931 6248-6262/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.088ms
    08-29 12:10:47.779 6248-7428/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner E/art: No implementation found for void org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_3(long, long, double, double) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13 and Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13__JJDD)
    08-29 12:10:47.792 6248-7428/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                      Process: com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner, PID: 6248
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_3(long, long, double, double) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13 and Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13__JJDD)
                                                                                          at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_3(Native Method)
                                                                                          at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny(Imgproc.java:1038)
                                                                                          at com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyAsyncTask.java:98)
                                                                                          at com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyAsyncTask.java:27)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
    08-29 12:15:47.845 6248-7428/com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6248 SIG: 9
```

My asyncTask class where I am performing OpenCV related operations:

```
package com.gurankas.bhism.documentscanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.core.TermCriteria;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.utils.Converters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by bhism on 8/23/2017.
 */

public class MyAsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask {
    private static final String TAG = "AsyncTask";
    Bitmap bitmap1;
    Context context;


    //constructor initializing the context field
    public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }


    //Main method for the computation of the image
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object[] objects)
    {

            //set-up of the image in the desired format for k-means clustering
            Mat samples = new Mat(((LensActivity)context).src.rows() * ((LensActivity)context).src.cols(), 3, CvType.CV_32F);
            for( int y = 0; y < ((LensActivity)context).src.rows(); y++ )
            {
                for( int x = 0; x < ((LensActivity)context).src.cols(); x++ )
                {
                    for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                    {
                        samples.put(x + y*((LensActivity)context).src.cols(), z, ((LensActivity)context).src.get(y,x)[z]);
                    }
                }
            }

            //applying k-means clustering
            int clusterCount = 2;
            Mat labels = new Mat();
            int attempts = 5;
            Mat centers = new Mat();
            Core.kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels, new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.MAX_ITER |
                            TermCriteria.EPS, 10000, 0.0001), attempts,
                    Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);


            //The image with the colour nearest to white will be considered as foreground
            double dstCenter0 = calcWhiteDist(centers.get(0, 0)[0], centers.get(0, 1)[0], centers.get(0, 2)[0]);
            double dstCenter1 = calcWhiteDist(centers.get(1, 0)[0], centers.get(1, 1)[0], centers.get(1, 2)[0]);
            int paperCluster = (dstCenter0 < dstCenter1)?0:1;


            //definition of 2 Mat objects needed for next step
            Mat srcRes = new Mat( ((LensActivity)context).src.size(), ((LensActivity)context).src.type() );
            Mat srcGray = new Mat();


            //Performing Segmentation ie displaying all foreground pixels as white and all background pixels as black
            for( int y = 0; y < ((LensActivity)context).src.rows(); y++ )
            {
                for( int x = 0; x < ((LensActivity)context).src.cols(); x++)
                {
                    int cluster_idx = (int)labels.get(x + y*((LensActivity)context).src.cols(),0)[0];
                    if(cluster_idx != paperCluster)
                    {
                        srcRes.put(y,x, 0, 0, 0, 255);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        srcRes.put(y,x, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                    }
                }
            }


            //Apply canny edge detection and then find contours
            Imgproc.cvtColor(((LensActivity)context).src, srcGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
             Imgproc.Canny(srcGray, srcGray, 50, 150);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

            Imgproc.findContours(srcGray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


            //Finding the biggest contour corresponding to the page in the image
            int index = 0;
            double maxim = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(0));

            for (int contourIdx = 1; contourIdx < contours.size();contourIdx++)
            {
                double temp;
                temp=Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
                if(maxim<temp)
                {
                    maxim=temp;
                    index=contourIdx;
                }
            }
            Mat drawing = Mat.zeros(srcRes.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Imgproc.drawContours(drawing, contours, index, new Scalar(255), 1);


            //lines corresponding to the biggest contours used to find the intersection points of these lines to find the corners
            Mat lines = new Mat();
            Imgproc.HoughLinesP(drawing, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, 70, 30, 10);

            ArrayList<Point> corners = new ArrayList<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < lines.cols(); j++) {
                    double[] line1 = lines.get(0, i);
                    double[] line2 = lines.get(0, j);

                    Point pt = findIntersection(line1, line2);
                    Log.d("com.packtpub.chapter9", pt.x+" "+pt.y);
                    if (pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0 && pt.x <= drawing.cols() && pt.y <= drawing.rows())
                    {
                        if(!exists(corners, pt)){
                            corners.add(pt);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Corner is "+ pt);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Point is " + pt);
                }
            }

            sortCorners(corners);


            //determination of resultant image size
            double top = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(0).x - corners.get(1).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(0).y - corners.get(1).y, 2));

            double right = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(1).x - corners.get(2).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(1).y - corners.get(2).y, 2));

            double bottom = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(2).x - corners.get(3).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(2).y - corners.get(3).y, 2));

            double left = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(3).x - corners.get(1).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(3).y - corners.get(1).y, 2));
            Mat quad = Mat.zeros(new Size(Math.max(top, bottom), Math.max(left, right)), CvType.CV_8UC3);


            //refernce corners
            ArrayList<Point> result_pts = new ArrayList<Point>();
            result_pts.add(new Point(0, 0));
            result_pts.add(new Point(quad.cols(), 0));
            result_pts.add(new Point(quad.cols(), quad.rows()));
            result_pts.add(new Point(0, quad.rows()));

            //perspective transformation
            Mat cornerPts = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners);
            Mat resultPts = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(result_pts);

            Mat transformation = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(cornerPts,
                    resultPts);
            Imgproc.warpPerspective(((LensActivity)context).srcOrig, quad, transformation,
                    quad.size());
            Imgproc.cvtColor(quad, quad, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

             Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(quad.cols(), quad.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Utils.matToBitmap(quad, bitmap);

            //bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getConfig());
            bitmap1 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
            return bitmap;

    }
    //identification of 4 corners of the quadrilateral with respect to the center
     void sortCorners(ArrayList<Point> corners)
    {
        ArrayList<Point> top, bottom;

        top = new ArrayList<Point>();
        bottom = new ArrayList<Point>();

        Point center = new Point();

        for(int i=0; i<corners.size(); i++){
            center.x += corners.get(i).x/corners.size();
            center.y += corners.get(i).y/corners.size();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)
        {
            if (corners.get(i).y < center.y)
                top.add(corners.get(i));
            else
                bottom.add(corners.get(i));
        }
        corners.clear();

        if (top.size() == 2 && bottom.size() == 2){
            Point top_left = top.get(0).x > top.get(1).x ?
                    top.get(1) : top.get(0);
            Point top_right = top.get(0).x > top.get(1).x ?
                    top.get(0) : top.get(1);
            Point bottom_left = bottom.get(0).x > bottom.get(1).x
                    ? bottom.get(1) : bottom.get(0);
            Point bottom_right = bottom.get(0).x > bottom.get(1).x
                    ? bottom.get(0) : bottom.get(1);

            top_left.x *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;
            top_left.y *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;

            top_right.x *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;
            top_right.y *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;

            bottom_left.x *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;
            bottom_left.y *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;

            bottom_right.x *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;
            bottom_right.y *= ((LensActivity)context).scaleFactor;

            corners.add(top_left);
            corners.add(top_right);
            corners.add(bottom_right);
            corners.add(bottom_left);
        }
    }

    //removal of redundant points in the intersection lines of the biggest contours
    static boolean exists(ArrayList<Point> corners, Point pt){
        for(int i=0; i<corners.size(); i++){
            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(i).x-pt.x,
                    2)+Math.pow(corners.get(i).y-pt.y, 2)) < 10){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static Point findIntersection(double[] line1, double[] line2) {
        double start_x1 = line1[0], start_y1 = line1[1],
                end_x1 = line1[2], end_y1 = line1[3], start_x2 =
                line2[0], start_y2 = line2[1], end_x2 = line2[2],
                end_y2 = line2[3];
        double denominator = ((start_x1 - end_x1) * (start_y2 -
                end_y2)) - ((start_y1 - end_y1) * (start_x2 - end_x2));

        if (denominator!=0)
        {
            Point pt = new Point();
            pt.x = ((start_x1 * end_y1 - start_y1 * end_x1) *
                    (start_x2 - end_x2) - (start_x1 - end_x1) *
                    (start_x2 * end_y2 - start_y2 * end_x2)) /
                    denominator;
            pt.y = ((start_x1 * end_y1 - start_y1 * end_x1) *
                    (start_y2 - end_y2) - (start_y1 - end_y1) *
                    (start_x2 * end_y2 - start_y2 * end_x2)) /
                    denominator;
            return pt;
        }
        else
            return new Point(-1, -1);
    }

    static double calcWhiteDist(double r, double g, double b){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(255 - r, 2) +
                Math.pow(255 - g, 2) + Math.pow(255 - b, 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        if(bitmap1!=null) {
            ((LensActivity)context).ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
        } else if (((LensActivity)context).errorMsg != null){
           // Toast.makeText(this, lensActivity.errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, ((LensActivity)context).errorMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

PS I had to cut short the Log due to the word limit

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue and found the solution to it here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9497

The issue stems from the version of OpenCV Manager (v3.0.0) on Google's Play Store is older than version used to develop (v3.1.1).

Uninstall OpenCV Manager on the Android phone and manually install the APK that comes in the OpenCV Android sdk zip file.

Comment: From what I can remember, I solved this by putting the appropriate .SO file corresponding to the device architecture in the project structure. But thank you :)